# is my murphy bed doable and safe?

Tags: bedroom

I want to build a murphy bed from scratch :
[image]
I don't know if that kind of structure can be made without drilling in the wall to fix the frame and without making some large base.

for Now on my 3d sketch, the base is made with two wood blocks making a 2"x8" section and more than 60" length. I dont'know if such a structure (I mean the frame and the bed) can fall on me when I down the bed (n.b the purple stuffs are hinges).

The sketch is not yet finished, I want to know if it worth to go further with that design. I can add more details if needed

Comment: Is it safe? not if not fixed to wall. Sooner or later [a small child will climb that and pull it down on top of themselves](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-36648589). Cue ambulance, police, courtroom?.

Comment: You appear not to understand basic concepts like weight and torque and center of gravity.  I strongly recommend that at the very least you study the installation manuals for commercial Murphy bed kits so you understand the importance of the restraining springs (not to mention proper anchoring to wall structures)

Comment: 2x8 frame will be HEAVY.  buy the kit with all the hardware you need. this will make putting the bed up or down so much easier and SAFER.   secure the wall part to the studs in the  wall.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say you have two options.  Attach the top of the murphy bed to studs; or build the bed with a substantial base which juts out from the wall quite a bit, like a sofa.  How to make the latter non-ridiculous would be a design challenge.

Comment: One more insane possibility: run beams from the top that butt into the opposite wall and have columns supporting them. (I'd never do this, but I think it would be safe and keep the floor clear.

Comment: Let's address the fundamental problem: without a set of restraining springs or hydraulic pistons, it'll never be safe enough to use.

Comment: Sure... or a winch.  But this makes the unsecured balance problem *even worse*.  Any sort of springing or damping will add the movable part's center of gravity to the stationary frame, shifting the CG significantly outward as the bed extends. Dynamic forces could move it even further.  Really, the best plan is bolt it to the wall studs.

Answer (score 3):

A typical murphy bed has springs to help lift the bed into the storage configuration. These springs will also pull the "closet" down unless it's secured in some way.

You can make the extended base foldable (possibly hidden as doors to the bed) so that when the bed is not in use it won't take up too much floor space. This can then also provide a location to lock the bed in the down position to avoid the murphy-bed slapstick routine.